# Sideways addition of bit pairs modulo 4

Tags: c, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation

Interpreting a `uint32` as a sequence of 16 pairs of bits (the imaginary type `uint2`), is there a more efficient algorithm to add these mod 4 than the following?

```
(x + (x>>2) + (x>>4) + (x>>6) + (x>>8) + (x>>10) + ... + (x>>30)) & 3
```

Moreover, I want to avoid branching instructions, to have it parallelizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to accumulate in the most significant two bits rather than the least significant two bits. One can then form partial sums byte-wise, and then sum the four partial byte sums with a single multiplication. This method is branchless and retains quite a bit of instruction level parallelism. Integer multiplication is fast on most modern processors even including many low-end CPUs used in embedded applications.

Especially for processors with low instruction-level parallelism, it can be advantageous to first accumulate nibble-wise, as this likely minimizes overall instruction count, at the expense of a slightly lengthier dependency chain. In the code below, selected by `ACCUMULATE_NIBBLE_WISE=1`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ACCUMULATE_NIBBLE_WISE (1)

uint32_t func_ref (uint32_t x)
{
    return ((x >>  0) + (x >>  2) + (x >>  4) + (x >>  6) + 
            (x >>  8) + (x >> 10) + (x >> 12) + (x >> 14) + 
            (x >> 16) + (x >> 18) + (x >> 20) + (x >> 22) +
            (x >> 24) + (x >> 26) + (x >> 28) + (x >> 30)) & 3;
}

uint32_t func (uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t mult = 0x01010101;
#if ACCUMULATE_NIBBLE_WISE
    uint32_t nibble_sum = (x & 0xcccccccc) + ((x << 2) & 0xcccccccc);
    uint32_t byte_sum = (nibble_sum + (nibble_sum << 4)) & 0xc0c0c0c0;
#else // !ACCUMULATE_NIBBLE_WISE
    uint32_t lolo = x & 0x03030303;
    uint32_t hilo = x & 0x0c0c0c0c;
    uint32_t lohi = x & 0x30303030;
    uint32_t hihi = x & 0xc0c0c0c0;
    uint32_t byte_sum = (lolo << 6) + (hilo << 4) + (lohi << 2) + hihi;
#endif // ACCUMULATE_NIBBLE_WISE
    return ((uint32_t)(byte_sum * mult)) >> 30;
}

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t a = 0;
    do {
        uint32_t ref = func_ref (a);
        uint32_t res = func (a);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("error: a=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", a, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        a++;
    } while (a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is a count-bits instruction in your target machine, the desired result is `__builtin_popcount(x & ~(UINT_MAX/3)) + __builtin_popcount(x) & 3;` (five operations). (`__builtin_popcount` is a GCC and Clang built-in function that counts the number of bits set.)

To see this, consider adding a sequence of two-bit numbers: *a*<sub>1</sub>*a*<sub>0</sub> + *b*<sub>1</sub>*b*<sub>0</sub> + *c*<sub>1</sub>*c*<sub>0</sub> + … Since the numbers are binary, this equals 2*a*<sub>1</sub> + *a*<sub>0</sub> + 2*b*<sub>1</sub> + *b*<sub>0</sub> + 2*b*<sub>1</sub> + *b*<sub>0</sub> + … = 2(*a*<sub>1</sub> + *b*<sub>1</sub> + *c*<sub>1</sub> + …) + (*a*<sub>0</sub> + *b*<sub>0</sub> + *c*<sub>0</sub> + …) = (*a*<sub>1</sub> + *b*<sub>1</sub> + *c*<sub>1</sub> + …) + (*a*<sub>1</sub> + *b*<sub>1</sub> + *c*<sub>1</sub> + … + *a*<sub>0</sub> + *b*<sub>0</sub> + *c*<sub>0</sub> + …).

The latter parenthesized term is the count of all the bits that are set (are one). The former term is the count of the high bit of each pair (the odd-numbered bits when numbering them from low bit 0 to high bit 31).

If there are an even number of bits in an `unsigned int`, `UINT_MAX/3` has the even-numbered bits set (FFFFFFFF<sub>16</sub> / 3 = 5555555555<sub>16</sub>). So `~(UINT_MAX/3)` has the odd-numbered bits set. Then `x & ~(UINT_MAX/3)` is just the odd-numbered bits of `x`. Its count plus the whole count gives the sum shown above, and `& 3` takes its low two bits.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75737871/2410359) fine answer, some variations on a theme that perform just a few shifts, masks and adds.

First add the 8 pairs of 2 bits.
Then add the 4 pairs of 2 bits ignoring the 3rd bit.
Then add the 2 pairs of 2 bits ignoring the 3rd-4th bit.
Then add the 1 pair of 2 bits ignoring the 3rd-5th bit.
Mask and return.

```
unsigned add_bit_pairs32_no_multiply(uint32_t x) {
  x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333) + (x & 0x33333333);
  x &= 0x33333333;
  x += x >> 4;
  x += x >> 8;
  x += x >> 16;
  return x & 3;
}

unsigned add_bit_pairs32_with_multiply(uint32_t x) {
  x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333)  + (x & 0x33333333);
  x = ((x >> 4) & 0x03030303)  + x;
  x &= 0x03030303;
  x *= 0x01010101;
  x >>= 24;
  return x & 3;
}
```

Comment: More options are always better. Both of these are encumbered by longer dependency chains compared to other variants, but `add_bit_pairs32_no_multiply()` in particular might perform better than other variants on simple in-order processors as it minimizes the number of required instructions.